# Static String path in Java

Tags: java, static, path, final

I've got only a main class in my small program and it's using a lot of path.
As they will not change while the program is running, I think I can put `static` in their declaration but not sure for the final. Moreover, I'm not sure where is the best place to declare my paths. Is it in the main class or just before?

Here's an example of my code:

```
package classtest;

public class ClassTest {
    // Should I put the path here?
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String dirPath = "C:/Users/test1/"; 
        String pathOut = "C:/Users/stats.csv"; 
        // or here?
    }   
}
```

Comment: Sure, you can declare them as final, so that they can't be changed afterwards, which looks like what you want : "As they will not change while the programm is running"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this kind of refactoring:

```
public class ClassTest {
    // Specify a base path for all paths to be used
    public static final String BASE_PATH = "C:/Users";
    // 1. If these paths will be used in several methods, declare them here
    public static final String dirPath = BASE_PATH + "/test1/"; 
    public static final String pathOut = BASE_PATH + "/stats.csv"; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // 2. If those paths will be used in the main method only, declare them here
        final String dirPath = BASE_PATH + "/test1/"; 
        final String pathOut = BASE_PATH + "/stats.csv"; 
    }   
}
```

**Static** members of a class should be declared **outside** the scope of any class method.

Comment: Thank you Sir, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: What would you name the package for this class? com.myproject.data ?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach is reading your paths from a [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file:

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
```

And use the properties wherever you would like. It makes refactoring later very easy:

```
prop.getProperty("diPath");
prop.getProperty("pathOut");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more common to make your paths arguments, so they can be set by the person running the program.

```
public class ClassTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: java ClassTest {dir} {output}");
            return;
        }
        String dirPath = args[0]; 
        String pathOut = args[1];

    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with this approach but it looks like convenient too, thank you Peter !

Comment: @zardlemalefique This is what command line arguments are usually used for.

Answer (score 1):

**`final`** keyword means that the value will **never reassigned**.

**`static`** keyword let the variable be a **class variable** instead of instance variable.

An additional note, generally class constants are written in uppercase with underscore delimiter, so I changed the names.

So if you like to declare them *"globally"* the best is to use a code similar to the following.

```
public class ClassTest {
    public static final String DIR_PATH = "C:/Users/test1/";
    public static final String PATH_OUT = "C:/Users/stats.csv";


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Use DIR_PATH or PATH_OUT as needed
    }   
}
```

Note that the previous code is useful only if you reuse the `DIR_PATH` or `PATH_OUT` variables in different methods. Otherwise defining the variable local to the main method is correct to limit the visibility to the only portion of code using it.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning best stylistic practices and making the proper adjustments.

Comment: Thank you Davide, this answer is also very clear and helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Try this .. It's the cleanest way :

```
public class ClassTest implements StaticPath {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.out.print(PATH_OUT);

    }   
}


interface StaticPath {

    public final static String PATH = "C:/Users/"; 

    public final static String PATH_OUT = PATH + "stats.csv";
    public final static String PATH_IN = PATH + "dyn.csv";

}
```

Comment: This would be unnecessarily confusing to someone reading this program.  Also, this wouldn't compile.

Comment: This compile fine ! and i's the best way if you want to store a 100 path for example instead of declaring them in the same java class with buisness logic. Maybe it's not the best approach for you but the code compile fine ;) and thks for the minus

Comment: There are things that are subjective in this regard, I'll give you that.  Deriving from interfaces (and therefore cluttering the project space) just so you can reference public, not private constant values is certainly not one such case.  Also, copy and paste this into an IDE and test it yourself before you label me a liar.  This code does *not* compile.

Comment: I tested it .. try your self plz and stop saying lays !

Comment: Neil is right, this doesn't compile. You have a typo here `StaticPAth` and here `SaticPath` (the names are different).